# ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative [IG BOT]

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

i got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Luca\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\INSTAGRAM BOT FINALE ( FORSE)\Python-Instagram-Bot-Scripts-main\selenium_script.py", line 105, in like_post_by_tag
        choices = random.sample(posts_list, amount)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\random.py", line 450, in sample
        raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
    ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

it is for an instagram bot and it crashes when its trying to click into a post

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sample a number of items greater than the number of items you are sampling from, then you will encounter this ValueError. You can either handle the error with an exception `except ValueError: choices = random.sample(posts_list, len(posts_list))` and then resample with a lower value, such as the size of the posts_list `num_posts_list = len(posts_list)` OR you can check the sizes of posts_list before you sample and then reduce the amount. `if amount > num_posts_list: amount = num_posts_list`